# Display problem of transform gizmo in blender 2.90 and 2.91

Tags: blender

Since yesterday night, I have a problem with blender when I try to transform an object. I think that the image below helps in explaining what happens. Instead of showing the transformation gizmo properly, a family of polygons or lines appears on the screen. When I deselect the object, those weird elements disappear. I noticed that the lines of arrows in the gizmo are not displayed, neither those of the navigation gizmo (the one in the top-right corner).  I am running a linux machine with Ubuntu 18.04.

[image]

The things that I have tried so far are:

1. Uninstall blender 2.90 from the ppa of Thomas Schiex
2. Install blender 2.91 from blender web page
3. Remove `.config/blender` folder
4. Click on Defaults->Load Factory Settings
5. Try to check almost any option in the settings
6. Check that `apt` has not updated/installed nothing since 08 Dec.

**Edit:** I have posted an answer below.
I have just solved the problem. Right after posting the question, blender crashed. This is the first time that has happened to me. In the crash log, I found that it is loading a `LibGL` library from another program through the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. After editing the environment variable, the problem has disappeared.

Comment: Please include the example in the question.

Comment: Post to the [blender.se] site instead.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. There is no need for an example. This happens right after opening the program. I have fixed it just by chance. I have edited the question with the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just solved the problem. Right after posting the question, blender crashed. This is the first time that has happened to me. In the crash log, I found that it is loading a `LibGL` library from another program through the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. After editing the environment variable, the problem has disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

run blender with , mode compatibilite   windows 8

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35505701)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).